# Emacs AucTeX - Folding natbib Citations

Tags: emacs, latex, auctex

In the Emacs AucTex environment, there exists a [fold mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Folding.html#Folding), which allows to hide much of the LaTeX markup to focus on the content.

I am using `natbib` citations, i.e. instead of `\cite{key}` citations I also have `\citep{key}` (and `\citep{key1,key2}`) citations in my document.

Unfortunately, AucTeX folds only the `\cite{key}` citations but leaves all `\citep{key}` citations untouched.

What do I have to do, to have also these natbib citations being folded in AucTeX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just wondered about this myself and found your post unanswered so had to look a bit further. I assume you've resolved the issue by now but perhaps my answer will help others in the future.

I run Emacs 24.5.1 and AUCTex 11.88.

The AUCTex folding customization can be found under Options(menu)->Customize Emacs(menu)->Browse Customization Groups(menu)
Then in the buffer that appears, follow the following branches from Group Emacs: Text -> Tex -> AUCTex -> Tex Fold and click Option where it lists Tex Fold Macro Spec List.

There you will find a list of the wrappers that fold into [c], currently probably only containing "cite". Add the natbib citations structures, I also added the Harvard ones.

Comment: No, I haven't solved the issue by now. If so, I would have posted my own answer here. Thanks - you're answer indeed solves the problem.